# Sampling Rate of Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, analog-sampling

It might be a stupid question but, I am currently using Arduino Uno with the 16MHz processor, what is maximum sampling rate of data available to me if I want to read data of a sensors such as accelerometer?

Comment: It depends how the accelerometer is read. Is it I2C? SPI? Serial? Can you provide a part number or link? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I m sorry for incomplete information,i am using MPU6050 with I2C .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a [page about I2C](http://www.gammon.com.au/i2c). The speed of I2C depends on a number of things, such as the I2C clock (which you can change) and also how many data bytes are in a "packet". There is a fixed overhead of the device address in each packet.

A broad rule-of-thumb would be around 4700 bytes per second for a single-byte payload at the default clock rate. You may also need to spend time asking for a reading. I haven't read the datasheet (which you didn't link).

The datasheet for the MPU6050 may give you more information about how fast it can respond.